# Angular 5 File upload in chunks to ASP NET returns with Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, fileapi

So, I am trying to upload big files in chunks using Angular 5 and the [fileapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fileapi)

This is how my request looks like:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileKey', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);
FileAPI.upload({
  url: 'http://localhost:22166/api/lbx/upload',
  headers: { 'authorization' : `Bearer ${this._svc.getToken()}`,
    // 'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${this.fileToUpload.name}; name=zip},
    files: {
      file: formData
    },
    // formData: true,
    // chunkSize: 1.0 * FileAPI.MB,
    progress: function (evt){
      console.log((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
    },
    complete: function (err, xhr){
      if (err) {
        const message = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).ExceptionMessage;
        parent.saving = false;
        parent.snack(message);
      } else {
        console.log('completed');
      }
    }
});
```

This is what my `Post` looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("lbx/upload")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadLBXProject()
    {
      try
      {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
          const string errorMsg = "Request content is not MIME multipart content and is unsupported.";
          AppEventLog.Error(string.Format(errorMsg));
          return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root)); //here it fails
        var uploadedFile = result.FileData.First();
        var originalFileName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(uploadedFile.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName).ToString();
        var uploadedFileInfo = new FileInfo(uploadedFile.LocalFileName);

        var part = ".part_1";

        //Get the orignal file name that was on the client side for "BodyPart_"
        var newZipFileName = uploadedFileInfo.FullName.Replace(uploadedFileInfo.Name, originalFileName + part);
        var regex = new Regex("\\d+");

        //If a zip file with the original name already exists, rename it
        while (File.Exists(newZipFileName))
        {
          var s = newZipFileName.Split('.');
          var np = ".part_" + (int.Parse(regex.Match(s[s.Length - 1]).Value) + 1);
          newZipFileName = newZipFileName.Replace(part, np);
          part = np;
        }

        var extractedFolderName = newZipFileName.Replace(".zip", "");

        if (Directory.Exists(extractedFolderName))
        {
          Directory.Delete(extractedFolderName, true);
        }

        File.Move(uploadedFileInfo.FullName, newZipFileName);

        AppEventLog.Info("upload of zip file finished");

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Last-Known-Byte");

        return ResponseMessage(response);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        //Delete the partially uploaded file if exception occured or if the user aborted
        var uploadedFilesPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");

        foreach (var fileInfo in new DirectoryInfo(uploadedFilesPath)
                                    .GetFiles())
        {
          File.Delete(fileInfo.FullName);
        }
        return InternalServerError(e);
      }
    }
```

This works fine without using the fileapi, but using this clientside code.

```
uploadLBX(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', file, file.name);
    const query = this._config.WEB_API_BASE_URL + this._config._api_urls.post.lbx.uploadzip;
    const headers = this.getHeaders();
    return this._http.post(query, formData, { headers: headers })
               .do(data => console.log(`file uploaded successfully`))
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

However, it does not work with big files, since my web.config already has the maximum value for requests:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
```

The exception:

> Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not
>   complete.

What can I do?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Added network request

[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the output from the network request? The part where the file is in the network request? The actual file form data in the request(if this makes sense)

Comment: sure. see my edit. thanks

Comment: What version of webapi are you using, I had this issue with 5.2.3 but it went away with 5.2.4